# Como fazer um select que traz os dados cadastrados em uma determinada semana?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Pretendo listar todos os dados cadastrados em uma determinada semana, alguém pode me ajudar?

Fiz algo parecido com o exemplo a baixo e não resulta.

```
public List<View_Venda> Venda_Semanais()
{
    List<View_Venda> lis = new List<View_Venda>();
    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(caminho);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conexao;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string lista = "select *from view_venda where data_registo=@data_registo <= DateTime.Now Add Day(-7) And DateTime.Today";
    cmd.CommandText = lista;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registo", DateTime.Today);
    conexao.Close();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    conexao.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        View_Venda obj = new View_Venda();
        obj.id_venda = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_venda"].ToString());
        obj.funcionario = dr["funcionario"].ToString();
        obj.fundo_inicial = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["fundo_inicial"].ToString());
        obj.total_veda_caixa = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total_veda_caixa"].ToString());
        obj.total_venda_multicaixa = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total_venda_multicaixa"].ToString());
        obj.total_multipagamento = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total_multipagamento"].ToString());
        obj.caixa_final = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["caixa_final"].ToString());
        obj.conciliacao = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["conciliacao"].ToString());
        obj.data_registo = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["data_registo"].ToString());
        lis.Add(obj);
    }
    return lis;
}
```

Comment: não retorna nada ou dispara exceção em algum momento? Tu pode formatar o código usando as opções do editor. (=

Comment: Desta forma também vai gerar erro

Answer (score 2):

Tenha no seu *SqlCommand * Dois parâmetros, um para a data inicial e outro para data final,(coloquei no exemplo como A e B respectivamente), A string do comando também estava incorreta, as datas que estava tentando passar devem ser inseridas nos parâmetros como abaixo

```
string lista = "select * from view_venda where data_registo >= @data_registoA and  data_registo<=@data_registoB";
    cmd.CommandText = lista;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registoA", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registoB", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: Desta forma vai gerar erro, na minha view não existe nenho atributo com nome data_registoA e B.

Comment: `data_registoaA` e `B` são apenas os parâmetros nomeados passados pro `select`. Isto vai ser substituído pelos valores passados no método `AddWithValue`

Comment: Estes 'atributos' São parametros, são somente os valores que serão substituídos e passados ao banco, no caso ele iria substituir para "data_registo >= '06/04/2017' and  data_registo<='13/04/2017' "